# Grails App using CXF plugin deployed in Tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat, grails, cxf

I am trying to deploy my Grails app, using the CXF plugin to expose some web services in Tomcat. In development mode all goes fine, but i can not acces those web service when i deploy the app in Tomcat.

If a try to navigate to this address app-name/services i get a list of all web services exposed, but if i try to see some of the wsdl of this webservices i get a 500 Internal error.

I tried to copy all the CXF jar to the lib folder in Tomcat, but no make any difference.

¿Some help? ¿Someone has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason the app was not dynamically generating the 'wsdl' in production enviroment. To partially solve this problem i wrap the 'wsdl' with the 'war'.